# Bundles uploaded via package manager not installed in OSGI AEM 6.3

Tags: aem

I have my bundle jar file along with other code(component JSPs) in a package(under apps/mytest/install).

When I upload and build the bundle from my local to stage environment, I don't see the "apps/mytest/install" folder itself in crx/de and the bundle doesn't get installed in the stage environment.

I can see a post here [URL](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2325452)related to this but cannot find "org.eclipse.equinox.region" bundle in any of our environments. Anyone has any other solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: You said you upload and build the package. Which steps do you perform in which order and in which environment? Uploading a previously built CRX package to a new environment (Staging) and _building_ it there would update the package with what's already in the environment. You'd have to _install_ the package.  Does the same bundle install correctly in your local environment?

Comment: I do build the package from my local environment. Then upload and install it in staging environment. It gets installed but the jar file in it doesn't (under apps/mytest/install folder). However, other than the jar file, all the other files(jsp, HTMLs, etc.) get installed.

Comment: Have you opened the package as a .zip to see what it contains?  It could be that there is a filter.xml definition that is only adding some of the files to the package that you expect, but not the bundle.